# Creating a Direct2D BitmapSource from a Win32 icon pointer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, directx, direct2d

I created an application in C# that gets icon images from window handles using user32.dll like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClassLong")]
private static extern int GetClassLongPtr32(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

public static IntPtr GetAppIcon(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    return WI.GetClassLongPtr32(hwnd, WI.ICON_SMALL);
}
```

And I want to create a BitmapSource from this icon pointer. Usually for WPF I would use

```
Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

But since I need the BitmapSource to draw it in a Direct2D render target I would need to use DirectX's BitmapSource

```
Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.DirectX.WindowImagingComponent.BitmapSource
```

How can I create this kind of BitmapSource using the icon handle or can I transfer one BitmapSource type to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ID2D1DeviceContext` has a method `CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap`.

With its help you can create an `ID2D1Bitmap`. The only thing you have to do is to create an `IWICBitmap` from your `HICON` and then create an `IWICFormatConverter`, so you can keep the alpha channel. You can do it this way (*The snippet from below is a delphi one but in C# should be very similar*):

```
procedure iconToD2D1Bitmap;
var
  hIcon: HICON;
  wicBitmap: IWICBitmap;
  wicConverter: IWICFormatConverter;
  wicFactory: IWICImagingFactory;  
  bitmapProps: D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1;
  bitmap: ID2D1Bitmap1;
begin
  // get a HICON
  hIcon := SendMessage(Handle, WM_GETICON, ICON_BIG, 0);
  try  
    // create wic imaging factory
    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IUnknown, wicFactory);

    wicFactory.CreateBitmapFromHICON(hIcon, wicBitmap);
    wicFactory.CreateFormatConverter(wicConverter);

    wicConverter.Initialize(wicBitmap, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, nil, 0, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut);

    bitmapProps.bitmapOptions := D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_NONE;
    bitmapProps.pixelFormat.format := DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    bitmapProps.pixelFormat.alphaMode := D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED;
    bitmapProps.dpiX := 96;
    bitmapProps.dpiY := 96;
    bitmapProps.colorContext := nil;    

    // deviceContext should be a valid D2D1DeviceContext
    deviceContext.CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(wicConverter, @bitmapProps, bitmap);

    // the bitmap variable contains your icon

  except
    //
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately the ImagingFactory that WindowsAPICodePack provides does not contain the method CreateBitmapFromHICON.
I think I will try using SharpDX instead, since it provides the methods you are using.

Comment: I don't know what `WindowsAPICodePack` exactly contains, but the `CreateBitmapFromHICON` is a `IWICImagingFactory` interface method, part of the [Wincodec library](http://goo.gl/sDFvjN)

Comment: I know, but I did not have access to this method without importing the interfaces since they were not included in the WindowsAPICodePack. I accepted your answer anyway because it was the right method and you helped me to find it in SharpDX. Thank you!