# Screen capture to Direct2D compatible bitmap

Tags: c++, bitmap, rendering, screenshot, direct2d

I need to capture the screen of a windows given its `HWND` handle and store the capture in a `ID2D1Bitmap` object in order to draw this bitmap by means of my render target.

How can I achive this result?

Comment: Note also, http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/115460/Direct-D-Capturing-a-dialog-background-in-a-bitmap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direct2D doesn't provide such functionality.

A possible way to go is if you first capture the screen via `GDI` (1) and then create a `ID2D1Bitmap` from the returned bitmap handle (2).

1. **Getting a `HBITMAP`** - Check this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5164267/3962893. You need the part till the `HBITMAP hbDesktop = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, width, height);` The `hbDesktop` variable will contain a handle to the screen captured bitmap.
2. **Creating an `ID2D1Bitmap` from a `HBITMAP`** - check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27500938/3962893. It copies an icon to a `ID2D1Bitmap`, but the workflow is identical. Except:

   `hIcon := SendMessage(Handle, WM_GETICON, ICON_BIG, 0); 
   ....
   wicFactory.CreateBitmapFromHICON(hIcon, wicBitmap);`

   that you have to change to:

   `wicFactory.CreateBitmapFromHBITMAP(hbDesktop, wicBitmap);`